# python telegram bot local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a code that will include both a conversation with a bot and a command that will cause the bot to send an image but I always get the same error

These are parts of the code.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                     level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()



from telegram import (ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove)
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters,
                          ConversationHandler)
from telegram.ext import Updater
updater = Updater(token='Token', use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
import telegram
bot = telegram.Bot('Token')

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

```
def sic(update, context):
    chat_id=update.effective_chat.id
    file = r"C:\Users\Yoav\Desktop\sicily_bot\user_photo.jpg"
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=open(file, 'rb'))
    bot.send_photo(chat_id, 'https://bitcoin.org/img/icons/opengraph.png')
```

```
def main():
    updater = Updater("Token", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        
        states={
            LOOKS: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Mehh|Okay.|Great|Amazing)$'), looks)],

            PHOTO: [MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo),
                    CommandHandler('skip', skip_photo)],

            EDUCATION: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, education),
                       CommandHandler('skip', skip_education)],

            BIO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, bio)]
        },

        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)], 
    )
    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
    dispatcher.add_handler(sic)
    sic = CommandHandler('sic', sic)
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\Desktop\sicily_bot\bot_comb.py", line 161, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\Desktop\sicily_bot\bot_comb.py", line 151, in main
    dispatcher.add_handler(sic)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sic' referenced before assignment
```

how can i fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Well, as the error says. You are using the variable `sic` in line `dispatcher.add_handler(sic)` without having initialized it before...

Comment: how can i initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sic = CommandHandler('sic', sic)
```

Is your intention with this line to override the `sic` function?

If you want to override the function, you should mark `sic` as a global variable:
[option 1]

```
def main():
    global sic
    ... # same as original
```

if that's not your intention, don't assign to `sic`. I don't know the telegram library, but my guess is that `CommandHandler` objects are supposed to be passed to `dispatcher.add_handler`. That means you should change your code to:

[option 2]

```
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('sic', sic))
```

Comment: oh thanks, i wasn't trying to override the sic function.
but when i type in chat "/sic" it doesn't start the function... any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Well, why don't you swap the line with dispatcher.add_handler and the one with sic = CommandHandler?

Comment: i tried it and i still get the same error


"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\Desktop\sicily_bot\bot_comb.py", line 140, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\Desktop\sicily_bot\bot_comb.py", line 132, in main
    sic = CommandHandler('sic', sic)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sic' referenced before assignment"